# Axios request from socket.io server side

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, axios, mern

I am trying to perform an axios request to the database from the socket.io server side, but am keep getting an error. How can I send Axios request or maybe there is a way to manipulate DB directly from socket.

```
    socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
        axios.get(`/api/rooms/${roomId}`)
            .then(room => {
                console.log(room);
                socket.to(roomId).emit("disc", user)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    });
```

**EDIT**

So I actually ended up using mongoose query, which did the trick

```
Room.findOne({ _id: roomId})
                .then(room => {
                    const filteredPlayers = room.players.filter(player => player !== user);
                    room.players = filteredPlayers;
                    room.save({players: room.players});
                })
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: If this is from the server-side, then you need a full URL for `axios()` that starts with `http://` or `https://` as there is no "default" URL to apply the domain from like there is in a browser.  Perhaps you mean to use `http://localhost` or something like that to refer to the local server.